DAX column totals are not giving expected totals when using the MIN



Name
Category
Item
Amount




Gary
food
rice
1


Gary
food
sugar
5


Gary
furniture
chair
8


Gary
furniture
table
4


John
food
rice
3


John
food
sugar
5


John
furniture
chair
6


John
furniture
table
7






Name
Food
Furniture
Total




Gary
12
36
48


John
16
39
55



Hello All
Trying to write this Dax but the column totals in power bi are giving me wrong totals. It gives the totals as 36 and 42 which is not the case.
The Dax is supposed to group the categories by name of person and multiply the total food category by 2 and multiply total furniture category by 3.
This is my Dax:
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    MIN(Sheet1[Category]) = "Food", SUM(Sheet1[Amount]) * 2,
    MIN(Sheet1[Category]) = "Furniture", SUM(Sheet1[Amount]) * 3
)


Well, I would say that the results are perfectly in line with your measure.  The issue with your DAX formula is that it does not handle the totals correctly. The SWITCH statement with SUM operates row by row but doesn't adjust the totals at the category level. For proper totals, you can try using a measure that groups and aggregates at the category level first, then applies the multiplier.
Try the following approach:
Total Amount = 
SUMX(
    VALUES(Sheet1[Category]),
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        Sheet1[Category] = "Food", CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Amount]) * 2),
        Sheet1[Category] = "Furniture", CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Amount]) * 3),
        0
    )
)


Truly grateful Michal. It worked. Thanks
